# Adding extra track to outside of circos plot (circlize, chordDiagram)

Tags: r, circlize

I'm trying to recreate this figure below, where the "to" variable (i.e. target genes) is further grouped into outer (labelled) categories (i.e. receptors).

[image]

I have generated some example data, unfortunately I'm not sure what format is needed for the additional outer categories, but it's possibly not far off the link format.

```
library(circlize)

links <- data.frame(from = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C"),
                     to = c("D", "E", "F", "D", "E"),
                    value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

categories <- data.frame(from = c("D", "E", "F", "D", "E"),
                         to = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
                         value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

chordDiagram(links)
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated!